# X server won't start after nvidia-xconfig command

Tags: linux, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, xorg, pacman

I proceeded with the instructions as per the [ArchWiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA). The `sudo pacman -S nvidia` command had around 46 options. I went for the last one  `linux416-rt-nvidia-390xx-390.48-3`because the version number seemed closer to the one prescribed by Nvidia (390.56) for my GPU (GeForce GT 610).

Problem: after a `sudo nvidia-xconfig` and reboot, X server does not open; all I see is a black screen with a blinking underscore in the top left corner.

Surprisingly, when you `chroot` through a live boot, the `nvidia-settings` work and shows the proper GPU details (but with an error loading driver in the console), but the X simply doesn't work. However, I can boot back in to X server by renaming/removing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file through `chroot`/`tty`, however `nvidia-settings` cannot be executed without configuring `xorg.conf` accordingly.

I thought it could be the version of the nvidia package installed so wanted to go for the default option, but I don't know how to uninstall and install a different option. `sudo pacman -S nvidia` just re-installs the same package and `sudo pacman -R nvidia` returns `target not found: nvidia`.

How to solve this problem? How to properly config nvidia in Arch/Manjaro Linux.

Comment: NEVER use nvidia-xconfig and never use a monolithic `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`! Things should work pretty much without any configuration. Also your driver might be incompatible with the latest xorg 1.20. You might want to check `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. If you want to install another driver, you should use something like `pacman -S nvidia-390xx`. You might want to use bash autocompletion with pacman.

Comment: @cylgalad Thanks for the info (wonder why ArchWiki doesn't provide any warning about this). The same problem occurs with the [minima configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA#Minimal_configuration). The error in the logs state `NVIDIA: Failed to initialize the NVIDIA kernel module.`, then `No devices detected` and `no screens found(EE)`. Error code 1 is returned at the end.

Comment: @cylgalad  I also tried your suggestion in pacman; still says target not found, bash autocomplete is not much help either, it merely shows all the executable binaries starting with `nvidia-` and none of them allows me to uninstall/reinstall the package.

Comment: To uninstall use `pacman -R package`. The error you gave isn't really informative (have you tried `modprobe nvidia` before starting X?), try to look at all the relevant lines that have `(EE)`, notably those pertaining to the video driver. You might post/upload your `Xorg.0.log` so I can take a look at it.